# Menu for methods in c#

Tags: c#, class, methods, menu, workflow

I've been learning C# and now I have some assignments to do. In java I did it in bluej IDE with creating classes for each exercises, but searching and asking some friends they tell me this cannot be done on C#. So I need a Menu.... there's like 100 exercises so I don't want to use Switch-Case.

I want something like this:

```
    class Program{
        public static void Main(String[] args){
        int opt;

        Console.WriteLine("program name");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("1. exercise 1");
        Console.WriteLine("2. exercise 2");
        Console.WriteLine("3. exercise 3");
        Console.WriteLine("4. exercise 4"); // to 100
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Choose exercise number: ");
        opt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //then call the exercise#
        Exercise + opt + ();
        }
     }
```

Or is there a better way to do it. I just want to learn C# and do the exercises in the proper way. Also if you know a better workflow to accomplish these 100 exercises it would be very nice and I would be very thankful!

Comment: Look into using a for loop and do some research on Collections

Comment: Maybe not the most recommended way, but I would use reflection here. Reverse the string to the method.

Comment: Wow! didn't think that someone would answers this question so fast! thx everyone! I've done my part and did some Research on: Collections(I knew that a little bit)(thx liquidsnake786), Reflections(Thx Sjips , Dario.pro and CaptainAnon), Dictionaries (OronDF343). Thx all guys! hope to improve my skills that much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a dictionary with the exercise number as the key and an Action as the value:

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<int, Action> exercises = new Dictionary<int, Action>
    {
        // put the numbers with the exercise method here:
        {1, () => Exercise1()},
        {2, () => Exercise2()},
    };
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int opt;

        Console.WriteLine("program name");
        Console.WriteLine();
        // Print valid names - Alternatively get them from a list
        foreach (int i in exercises.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}. Exercise {0}", i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Choose exercise number: ");
        opt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // call like this:
        exercises[opt]();
    }
 }
```

The advantage here is that it supports any method name and does not require reflection.

Comment: Not sure who voted down, but you should provide feedback as to why you voted down.

Comment: Thank you @OronDF343 your solutions is what I've been looking for. I would give you an upvote but well just got <15 of reputations. thx for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection. Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            int opt;

            Console.WriteLine("program name");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ". exercise " + i);
                // or use:
                // Console.WriteLine("{0}. exercise {0}", i); 
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Choose exercise number: ");
            opt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MethodInfo info = (typeof(Program)).GetMethod("Exercise" + opt.ToString());

            //then call the exercise#
            info.Invoke(null, null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Exercise1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exercise 1 executing..");
        }

        public static void Exercise2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exercise 2 executing..");
        }
    }
}
```

You have to write your own Exercise3, ..., Exercise100.

Comment: Just combine this answer with a for-loop for the menu items: for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) Console.WriteLine("{0}, Exercise {0}", i);

Comment: @Sjips thx for your answer so quick, thanks to you I know another way to accomplish my goals. Also wanted to give you an upvote but my reputation is not enough. Now I know a way far more of reflection thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to dynamaically call a method based on user selection. I have to use reflection then.

If you are learning C#, I think it's an advanced topic. Anyway check this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/getmethod

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: thx because of your link and Sjips answer I know how to implement reflection on my problem. the same as the others I would like to upvote you but not sufficient reputation. thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

you can use a for loop to keep incrementing the numbers;

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("program name");
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ". exercise " + i);
            }

        }
```

the loop means for an integer i, loop until it is less than or equal to by 100 and increment 1 each time (i++)

Comment: appologies - i thought the question was how you write out 100 lines to the console without repetition.

Comment: hehe no problem, that happens (by the way didn't downvote you) have a nice day.